# v-for and component external (croppa)

Tags: vue.js

I have a dynamic component with Vue Croppa.

```
<croppa v-for="(image, key) in images" :key="key" ...props></croppa>
```

If I add an element in `images`, it add a new croppa components and work perfect.

The problem is when I try to remove an element.

For example, if I added 3 images:

```
images: [
'image1.png',
'image2.png',
'image3.png,
]
```

if I deleted `image2 (index: 1)` it remove image3.

What I need to do to preserve all config (initial-image, position, flipX, etc...) of croppa by position?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `index` argument of `v-for` directive (in your case `key`) is reliable way to set item `key` attribute only if looped array (in your case `images`) is not going to be mutated.

In example above, when `images` length changes indexes of rendered items stay the same. Meaning, if second item has been deleted, renderer can notice changes of key indexes
from `0, 1, 2` to `0, 1`
Thus, the item with last index `2` is removed.

In order to achieve expected behavior, `key` attribute should be set to a unique value. For array of objects it is usually an `id` or any unique property. For array of strings (if values in array are unique) the `key` attribute can be set to that value. Example:

```
<croppa 
  v-for="image in images" 
  :key="image" 
/>
```

In case if some values in that array are not unique (which should be assumed if values come from external source - API, user input, etc), `key` attribute should be set to concatenated value and index. Example:

```
<croppa 
  v-for="(image, index) in images" 
  :key="`${image}${index}`" 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tested and doesn't work. When I added 3 Croppa with index `${image}${index}` and I did a splice(1, 1); (just for test and remove the second element of array `image`) it still showing the element `0, 1` and not `0, 2`

Comment: I added `:key="JSON.stringify(image)"`and seems like it works. Weird thing